# Flutter / Dart global variable list overwriting all list items with most recent list addition

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables

I have a single page application for form data that takes a list of text and photos and creates a word document.

When looking at the document lists I noticed that all entries of have the most recently added values.

I am using a global variable like this:

```
class FormData {
  static String title = '';
  static String procedureCovers = '';
  static String department = '';
  static String section = '';
  static String isolationOfficer = '';
  static String supervisor = '';
  static String reviewer = '';
  static List<dynamic> mechanicalIsolations = [];
  static List<dynamic> electricalIsolations = [];
  static dynamic isolationOfficersSignature;
  static dynamic supervisorsSignature;
  static dynamic reviewersSignature;
}
```

Most of the form data works fine, it is just when I go to edit the lists. That I see the problem over overwriting variables.

The format of my list elements are like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> mechanicalIsolationData = {
  'isolation': '',
  'isolateAt': '',
  'circuitValve': '',
  'imageFilePath': '',
  'notes': '',
};


Map<String, dynamic> electricalIsolationData = {
  'isolation': '',
  'isolateAt': '',
  'circuitValve': '',
  'notes': '',
};
```

And I am adding what I thought would be a new blank instance of the list entry:

```
FormData.mechanicalIsolations.add(mechanicalIsolationData);
```

But the new list item has the value of the previous list item.

Then when I go to set the value of of the most recent list item field it then overwrites all list items with the new value. I set it like this:

```
FormData.mechanicalIsolations[widget.listIndex]['isolation'] = text;
```

I have checked the list index and it is correct number, I have checked the value it is being set to and it is different. But it still overwrites all the previous list elements with that value.

I know the way I have done it is wrong I am just not sure what exactly is causing it and what best to do to fix it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not entirely clear from the code that you posted, but the problem is most likely caused by your Maps (`mechanicalIsolationData` and `electricalIsolationData`) being global variables. So when you think that you add a new blank instance to the List with `FormData.mechanicalIsolations.add(mechanicalIsolationData);` , you don't add a new instance, you just add a reference to the List, that points to the same `mechanicalIsolationData` object. As you later change the values in your `mechanicalIsolationData` Map, all your list elements get updated, as they all point to the same object.

Long story short: you are reusing a global variable, and keep adding references to your list that point to the same variable, therefore end up with a list with identical elements.

To avoid this, make sure, that you instantiate a new Map every time you call the method, that is responsible to populate `mechanicalIsolationData` or `electricalIsolationData`. Like this:

```
addMechanicalIsolationData(String isolationValue, int isolateAtValue, String circutValveValue, String path, String notes){
   Map<String, dynamic> mechanicalIsolationData = Map();

   mechanicalIsolationData['isolation'] = isolationValue;
   mechanicalIsolationData['isolateAt'] = isolateAtValue;
   mechanicalIsolationData['circuitValve'] = circuitValveValue;
   mechanicalIsolationData['imageFilePath'] = path;
   mechanicalIsolationData['notes'] = notes;

   mechanicalIsolations.add(mechanicalIsolationData);
}
```